# Event handling for a dynamically added user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control say SearchVendor.ascx which contains 4 buttons a gridview and another user control.
I need to load the control dynamically actually as a modal pop up

I get this code

```
var uc = Page.LoadControl("~/blah/VendorProductSearch.ascx") as VPSearch;
uc.ShowVPSearch(true);
_tempPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(uc);
```

it works fine the control gets loaded properly but onclick of any button the second time the control disappears ???

I want the dynamically added control to remain until the user clicks on the cancel button

Any idea as to how to achive this ?

Thanks & Regards,
Francis P.

Comment: So to be clear, is the control disappearing after a postback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the control to the page after every postback. I am working on something similar with an unknown number of controls and I keep a count of the number added so I can re-add them on postback.  To remove it on Cancel, you'll need to call Controls.Remove "myUserControlID" (passing in the ID you assigned to it).

```
public int AddressCount
{
    get
    {
       string s = (string)ViewState["addressCount"];
       return ((s == null) ? 1 : Convert.ToInt32(s));
    }

    private set { ViewState["addressCount"] = value.ToString(); }
}    

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < AddressCount; i++) 
   {
      Control ai = LoadControl("~/controls/addressItem.ascx");
      addressContainer.Controls.Add(ai); // addressContainer is a PlaceHolder control on the page
   }
}
```